# Robot and keyPress

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

What sort of code need to be passed to the JavaFX Robot when using the `keyPress` method?

For example, the example below enters a `1`, not an `a`, so I suppose there is a mapping somewhere.

```
Robot robot = com.sun.glass.ui.Application.GetApplication().createRobot();
robot.keyPress(((int) 'a');
```

Note: this is the JavaFX robot, not the AWT one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Codes are defined as constants in javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.

With the glass robot, you can use the deprecated method `impl_getCode`:

```
Robot robot = com.sun.glass.ui.Application.GetApplication().createRobot();
robot.keyPress(KeyCode.A.impl_getCode());
```

You can also use the FXRobot, which takes KeyCodes as parameters:

```
FXRobot robot = FXRobotFactory.createRobot(scene);
robot.keyPress(javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.A);
```

Comment: It looks for me, although I have no proof yet, that com.sun.glass.ui.Robot is now kind of deprecated in favor of com.sun.javafx.robot.FXRobot. Does particular robot implementation matters in your case?

Comment: Actually [this message](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2012-February/000760.html) seems to say that FXRobot might be removed while the glass robot is used in their test suite... This is confusing...

Comment: Indeed. Deprecations seem to contradict each other here. It worth opening an isuue to make the things clear